# Headless testing for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, testing

I am looking for a headless testing environment for javascript... something like [ZombieJS](http://zombie.labnotes.org/), but without relying on nodejs, and something which has been around for a bit longer and is therefore, hopefully, a bit more stable...

Ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Would [JsTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) work for you?

That still needs a browser visiting a page, but as I understand you can just keep it open and forget about it, and get at the tests from the command line or wherever you want.

Comment: I have come accross JsTestDriver before, but unfortunately it doesnt quite do what we want... JsTestDriver is more of a unit testing framework... I am looking for a framework that will effectively walk through a website taking a predefined path and report any errors it encounters along the way.

Comment: *nods* Wasn't sure what kind of testing you meant, and assumed unit.